# Bootstrap Auto adjust column Width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have created Two column page.Like,

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-10"></div>
</div>
```

Does bootstrap have option like adjusting the width of the column if first column doesn't have data.?

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is no! If you take a look at [the source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins/grid.less#L41) you'll see that for `col-sm` the width is defined in terms of percent:

```css
// Generate the small columns
.make-sm-column(@columns; @gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left:  (@gutter / 2);
  padding-right: (@gutter / 2);

  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    float: left;
    width: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  }
}
```

so your best shot would be to assign correct classes on the server side *OR* write a small script that checks the content and adapts the classes.