# Bootstrap grid with variable width columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way in Boostrap to make grid columns adjust according to the width of the viewport? I have the following page, where the first column is `col-md-3` and the second `col-md-9`:

[image]

The right hand column is supposed to show a list of files when the user selects a folder in the left hand column. Yet the column widths stay fixed, and if I reduce the screen width just the tiny bit, the right-hand column is moved to below the left-hand column. The left hand column then fills the height and width of the screen, and the file list column is invisble below it, making for a very bad UX.

Is there some way, preferably in Bootstrap, to have the columns adjust their width in proportion to the screen width, or is there some alternative to Bootstrap with a grid that can work like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31339759/bootstrap-auto-adjust-column-width

Comment: You could change the class `col-md-3` to `col-sm-3` so the breakpoint when it occupies the full width is in a smaller viewport do the same with the other col too. But width is fixed and would be 3/12 and 9/12 of the available width respectively.

Comment: @Jeremy He's using bootstrap-v3 aparently so class names helpers are different from the v4. [ https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/ ]

Comment: *grid columns adjust according to the width of the viewport*, Thats what the -md- does, it makes them go underneath eachother and take 100% width at a viewport under 567 px. You can also use -xs-, -sm- and -lg- (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/ at "grid options"). Or am I understandig this wrong?

Comment: @Fecosos Oh I notice, edited it

Comment: @ZimSystem Nonsense. Bootstrap 3 is well known for its 12 column grid, used with CCS classes such as `row` and e.g. `col-md-6`, which gives a half-row column. How it achieves that is immaterial, it is defined by CSS.

Comment: @ZimSystem Touche. Tag removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this using css grid.

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
.container{
  display:grid;
  grid-template: 100vh / repeat(12, 1fr);
  color:#fff;
}
.container > div{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.left-panel{
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  background: #F7A072;
}
.right-panel{
  grid-column: 4 / -1;
  background: #0FA3B1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left-panel">Left</div>
    <div class="right-panel">Right</div>
  </div>
</body>
```